# Grok pattern for logs sent to logstash

Tags: regex, logstash-grok, grok

I have haproxy logs that need to be sent to logstash, I am trying to grok the captured request headers. Can you please suggest the grok pattern?

Here is section of log that has the Referrer|User-Agent|X-Forwarded-For|True-Client-IP

> {https://my-dev.mysite.com/|Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X
>   10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95
>   Safari/537.36|161.987.654.321, 122.486.243.921,
>   21.103.137.111|161.987.654.321}

I am new Grok patterns so need your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one:

```
{%{URI:referrer}\|%{GREEDYDATA:user-agent}\|%{DATA:x-forwarded-for}\|%{IP:ip}}
```

It will work if you use real IPs.

Comment: Almost got it working. Thanks for your help. Here is followup question ...   How to remove the IP4 & IP6 ? I aslo wanted to rename 'x' with x-forwarded-for & 'ip' with True-Client-IP. Thanks again for your help

Comment: You can use %{IPV4:TrueClientIP} instead of %{IP:TrueClientIP}. If I could help you, please accept my anwser.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me ...

```
  {%{DATA:referrer}\|%{GREEDYDATA:user-agent}\|%{DATA:XForwardedFor}\|%{IP:TrueClientIP}}
```